# How to get the latest record on big query based on field date

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group

This is my query

```
SELECT producto, ROUND(precio_medio,2) as precio, fecha, mpio, cod_dpto, tipo, presentacion FROM DATABASE where categoria="Arrendamiento de tierras" and tipo="Arrendamiento de tierras" and producto="Cabeza de ganado mensual para pastoreo, terreno inclinado/ondulado con agua" and presentacion ="Arriendo"
```

it return
[id, producto, precio, fecha,mpio,cod_dpto, presentacion]
[image]

So I want to get only the lates record of each one Popayan and Piendamo based in the field fecha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Big Query, you can use arrays for this. Assuming that you want the row with the most recent `fecha` per `mpio`:

```sql
select * except(ar)
from (  
    select 
        mpio,
        array_agg(
            struct(id, producto, precio, mpio,cod_dpto, presentacion)
            order by fecha desc limit 1
        ) ar
    from database
    where 
        categoria="Arrendamiento de tierras" 
        and tipo="Arrendamiento de tierras" 
        and producto="Cabeza de ganado mensual para pastoreo, terreno inclinado/ondulado con agua" 
        and presentacion ="Arriendo"
    group by mpio
) x, unnest(x.ar)
```

A more standard approach is to use window functions:

```
select * except(rn)
from (
    select 
        fecha, id, producto, precio, mpio,cod_dpto, presentacion,
        row_number() over(partition by mpio order by fecha desc) rn
    from database
    where 
        categoria="Arrendamiento de tierras" 
        and tipo="Arrendamiento de tierras" 
        and producto="Cabeza de ganado mensual para pastoreo, terreno inclinado/ondulado con agua" 
        and presentacion ="Arriendo"
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Even "simpler" version (for BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
    mpio,
    ARRAY_AGG(
        STRUCT(id, producto, precio, fecha, cod_dpto, presentacion)
        ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 1
    )[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM `project.dataset.table`  
WHERE categoria="Arrendamiento de tierras" 
  AND tipo="Arrendamiento de tierras" 
  AND producto="Cabeza de ganado mensual para pastoreo, terreno inclinado/ondulado con agua" 
  AND presentacion ="Arriendo"
GROUP BY mpio
```