# change value in column if another column is duplicated (BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Say I have a table like

```
id   foo    bar
---+-----+-----
1    null    a
1    b       a
2    null    null
.
.
```

I want to create a table where the value in `foo` is null where `id` is duplicated, and then only keep one record with the duplicated `id`. All columns are the same but `foo` when the `id` is the same.
The result would then be

```
id   foo    bar
---+-----+------
1    null    a
2    null    null
.
.
```

I have tried first finding the duplicated `id`, which is easy, but I struggle with the "extract `foo` as null" part.

Comment: `cast(null as target_datatype) as foo`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the latest record on big query based on field date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63695557/how-to-get-the-latest-record-on-big-query-based-on-field-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider below.

```sql
-- sample data
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 1 id, null foo, 'a' bar UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'b', 'a' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, null, null
)
-- query starts here
SELECT id, IF(COUNT(id) > 1, null, ANY_VALUE(foo)) foo, ANY_VALUE(bar) bar
  FROM sample_table
 GROUP BY id;
```

**Query result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When there are duplicates, use self `left join` to exclude records that are not null from the table:

This query will return duplicated ids with at least one `foo = null` condition.

```
select id, max(foo) as foo
  from mytable
  group by id
  having sum(case when foo is null then 1 else 0 end) >= 1 and count(1) > 1
```

Using `left join` with a condition `s.id is null` will excludes data that is not null

```
select t.*
from mytable t
left join (
  select id, max(foo) as foo
  from mytable
  group by id
  having sum(case when foo is null then 1 else 0 end) >= 1 and count(1) > 1
) as s on s.id = t.id and s.foo = t.foo
where s.id is null;
```